# Close Modal Popup using Esc key on keyboard

Tags: javascript, reactjs, keyboard-events, reactstrap, modalpopup

I need to close the modal also using the "ESC" key, at the moment it is closing the "CLOSE" and "CONFIRM" button. i'm using reactstrap, react hooks.
keyboard {show} and handleClose
it didn't work.

Here is the code:

```
const DeleteUserModal = props => {
    const { user, show } = props;

    const deleteUser = async () => {
        await props.removeUser(user);
        props.onCloseModal();
    };

    const handleKeyPress = target => {
        if (target.charCode === ENTER_KEY) {
            deleteUser();
        }
    };
    


    return (
        <div onKeyPress={handleKeyPress}>
            <Modal isOpen={show} toggle={props.onCloseModal}  >
                
                <ModalHeader toggle={props.onCloseModal}>
                    <IntlMessages id="modal.delete.user.title" />
                </ModalHeader>

                <ModalBody>
                    <IntlMessages id="modal.delete.user.description" />
                </ModalBody>

                <ModalFooter>
                    <Button className="cancel" onClick={props.onCloseModal}>
                        <IntlMessages id="modal.common.cancel" />
                    </Button>
                    <Button className="action" onClick={deleteUser}>
                        <IntlMessages id="modal.common.ok" />
                    </Button>
                </ModalFooter>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    );
};

export default DeleteUserModal;
```

follows the modal with two actions

Comment: What do you mean by closing a button?

Comment: Kindly refer the following https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#options provided by bootstrap

Comment: I need to close the modal by pressing the ESC key. At the moment it closes when pressing the confirm button or cancel the action. I'm checking the documentation, but when I put the code, nothing happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In vanilla JavaScript, you could do:

```js
document.onkeydown = function (evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode == 27) {
        // Escape key pressed
        props.onCloseModal();
    }
};
```

Comment: I'm assuming `props.onCloseModal();` is used to close the modal. I have never used reactjs in my life, so correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: I will do this test

Comment: Does this work with Windows and Mac and Linux??

Comment: Ok, JS is a hack, React is a hack-of-a-hack, but accepted answer as piling more hacks on top of hacks?! It's insane. Please don't do this. For your own sanity

Answer (score 34):

You can setup an event listener.

```
 useEffect(() => {
      const close = (e) => {
        if(e.keyCode === 27){
          props.onCloseModal()
        }
      }
      window.addEventListener('keydown', close)
    return () => window.removeEventListener('keydown', close)
  },[])
```

Comment: `keyCode` is deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode. Use `e.key === 'Escape` instead', for better international keyboard support.

Comment: what would be the class component equivalent of this?

Comment: Is there a way to do this in react without touching the actual dom?

Comment: Not only will this not work without placing the state variable change in the useEffect() parameter (the brackets at the end), it leaves your listener dangling forver inside your app!

Answer (score 1):

You can check bootstrap documentation.

If nothing found, then you could add an event listener to the ESC key press and than call onCloseModal

Comment: I will do this test

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using TypeScript and the new `event.key` property:

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
    const closeOnEscapePressed = (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
      if (e.key === "Escape") {
        props.onCloseModal();
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener("keydown", closeOnEscapePressed);
    return () =>
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", closeOnEscapePressed);
  }, []);
```